# Ballerina: build image and push to gcr.io via k8s plugin

Tags: docker, kubernetes, ballerina

I'm using a simple `ballerina` code to build my program (simple hello world) with `ballerinax/kubernetes` annotations. The service is being compiled succesfully and accessible via the specific bind port from local host.

When configuration a kubernetes deployment I'm specifying the image build and push flags:

```
@kubernetes:Deployment {
    replicas: 2,
    name: "hello-deployment",
    image: "gcr.io/<gct-project-name>/hello-ballerina:0.0.2",
    imagePullPolicy: "always",
    buildImage: true,
    push: true
}
```

When building the source code:

```
ballerina build hello.bal
```

This is what I'm getting:

```
Compiling source
    hello.bal

Generating executable
    ./target/hello.balx
    @docker          - complete 3/3

    Run following command to start docker container:
    docker run -d -p 9090:9090 gcr.io/<gcr-project-name>/hello-ballerina:0.0.2

    @kubernetes:Service              - complete 1/1
    @kubernetes:Deployment           - complete 1/1
error [k8s plugin]: Unable to push docker image: unauthorized: You don't have the needed permissions to perform this operation, and you may have invalid credentials. To authenticate your request, follow the steps in: https://cloud.google.com/container-registry/docs/advanced-authentication
```

Note that when pushing it manually via docker on my local machine it works find and the new image is getting pushed.

What am I missing? Is there a way to tell ballerina about docker registry credentials via the `kubernetes` package?

Answer (score 2):

Ballerina doesn't support gcloud docker registry yet, but it supports dockerhub. 
Please refer [sample6](https://github.com/ballerinax/kubernetes/tree/master/samples/sample6) for more info.

Basically, you can export docker registry username and password as environment variables.

Please create an issue at https://github.com/ballerinax/kubernetes/issues for track this.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like a problem with Container Registry, you are not able to authenticate.

> To authenticate to Container Registry, use  `gcloud`  as a Docker credential helper. To do so, run the following command:
>
> `gcloud auth configure-docker`
>
> You need to run this command once to authenticate to Container Registry.
>   We strongly recommend that you use this method when possible. It provides secure, short-lived access to your project resources.

You can check yourself the steps for  [Container Registry Authentication Methods](https://cloud.google.com/container-registry/docs/advanced-authentication)